# How to get gcm_sender_id for website in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use push notification for my web site..

I am trying fcm. In the Google documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) they told us to use gcm_sender_id in `manifest.json` file, but I don't find it any where in firebase page https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fir-98798789/overview

Also they have mentioned

> Don't confuse the "browser sender ID" with the project-specific sender ID value shown in your Firebase project settings. The browser sender ID for manifest.json is a fixed value, common among all FCM JavaScript clients.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The sender ID that you enter in the manifest.json of your web app is independent of your Firebase project. It is the same for all web apps (yours, mine, everybody's):

```
"gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"
```

So just copy/paste the line above into the manifest.json for your project. See [this section of the FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#configure_the_browser_to_receive_messages).

Comment: Somehow it actually works without it. See answer below for more details. Have you had (or would you have) a chance to test this behaviour out? I'm not sure if I'm some outlier here...

Answer (score 7):

Goto https://console.firebase.google.com -> select your project.

**Settings** -> **Cloud Messaging** -> **Project credentials** -> **Sender ID**

Hope this help!

Comment: Project credentials appears nowhere in the Cloud Messaging panel.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like Firebase Messaging actually works even if you skip this step. Look at https://web-push-demo-11213.firebaseapp.com as an example.

This demo website doesn't even have a manifest but is able to talk to FCM, get tokens, refresh them and so on.. Sorry you won't be able to actually send a push though since you don't know the auth key, but you get the idea - I've tested it, it works.

In light of this, not sure why this manifest requirement though.

Also, looking at the FCM SDK source on github, looks like they only throw an error if you have a manifest with a `gcm_sender_id` that's not `103953800507`. For everything else (the `gcm_sender_id` field in manifest missing, or even the manifest itself missing from the website), it works as fine.

See the code here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/messaging/src/controllers/window-controller.ts#L329-L355

Comment: Yes it works but there are a couple of browsers that still need it 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/web-push-interop-wins#reality_of_these_changes